# Is it possible to intercept a request before the request body will be received

Tags: java, tomcat

The original problem: limit multipart file upload size by e.g. `10mb` on the level of Tomcat.

My current solution (based on Spring Boot's `StandardMultipartHttpServletRequest`) checks internally the `Content-Length` request header first. Sounds fine so far...

But I see that for huge files the notable delay (which corresponds to the file size) appears before this check comes in action and even before any servlet filter logic. In fact, I get this delay before (or somewhere inside) `org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint`, which is the second call in the stacktrace (the first one is `Thread`).

Looks like tomcat loads the complete request body on the low level before any application logic is applied.

By contrast, when I wrap Tomcat in Nginx as a reverse proxy and limit file size in Nginx (which also checks the header only), it breaks upload instantly.

The question: is it technically possible to perform any logic in Tomcat before request body upload is done? In particular, for limiting file size?

Comment: Do you want to do it through the tomcat configuration ?

Comment: @AnishB. in the ideal world I would prefer to be able to return some JSON in respose. But if it's not possible, configuration-wise is also acceptable.

Comment: There are two things happening, here. First, if the client doesn't send an `Expect: 100-continue` header with the `Content-Type` then the server can't reject the request "early". Second, if the client sends the whole file, there isn't a way to tell the client to stop in the middle. I suspect that Nginx terminates the connection. Tomcat doesn't do that, and instead reads the whole request in order to flush it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Steps to set the upload size of tomcat :

*1. Go to the Tomcat's webapps/manager/WEB-INF folder and open* `web.xml`

*2. You will find this tag*  `<multipart-config>`, like this below :

```
<multipart-config>
  <!-- 50MB max (size in bytes) -->
  <max-file-size>52428800</max-file-size>
  <max-request-size>52428800</max-request-size>
  <file-size-threshold>0</file-size-threshold>
</multipart-config>
```

*3. Change the above configuration to your needs.*

*4.For nginx, set the client_max_body_size in any block where you want :*

Example :

```
http {
    client_max_body_size 50M;
}
```

Hope this helps you :)

Comment: The multipart-config does the trick! But I decided to use a somewhat different combination of approaches: 1. validate file size on **frontend** to provide a user-friendly error; 2. the limit on the **Nginx** level; 3. the original app-level limit based on `StandardMultipartHttpServletRequest` - just additionally.